# Search by a condition on an object keys Jayway jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath, jayway

I have an object that looks like:

```json
{
    "item_1": {...},
    "item_2": {...},
    "object_1": {...}
}
```

Is there a way I could only take the objects which keys match the regex `item.*`?
The return object would be:

```json
{
    "item_1": {...},
    "item_2": {...},
}
```

I tried playing around with the `.keys()` function but it doesn't seem like I can operate on the return value.

Thanks in advance :)